# ASP.MVC ENTITY Code First (problema extranho)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Não sei se estou fazendo algo errado (provavelmente sim). Mas o EF está persistindo os dados em uma BD e em uma tabela que ele cria sozinho.

Eu já repeti este passo-a-passo 2 vezes e o resultado é o mesmo.

1-Eu crio uma Solução web MVC que chamo de Modelo-Index. (A ideia era praticar paginação e filtros, mas... gastei o dia todo pra nada...)

2-Crio um "sub" projeto dentro desa solução chamado Dominio e crio uma classe POCO chamada Aluno com, Id, Matricula, Nome e Observação.

3-Crio outro "Sub" projeto e chamo de Persistencia. Instalo nele o EntityFramework. Adiciono uma classe CadastroAlunosDbContext.cs como a seguir:

```
using Dominio;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
namespace Persistencia
{
public class CadastroAlunosDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().ToTable("Alunos");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
}
```

Depois vou no App.config deste projeto Persistencia e adiciono:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CadastroAlunosDbContext" connectionString="Server=NB-SAUDE-03;Database=CadastroAlunos;User Id=sa;Password=Master123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Perceba que meu server se chama Server=NB-SAUDE-03
Eu especifico inclusive a base de dados: **Database=CadastroAlunos**
Então executo os seguintes comandos no PackageManagerConsole:

*Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Persistencia -StartUpProjectName Persistencia*

*Add-Migration "Criação Base" -ProjectName Persistencia -StartUpProjectName Persistencia*

*Update-Database -ProjectName Persistencia -StartUpProjectName Persistencia*

### ------Até aqui Tudo funciona como esperado---------

Vou no SQL Server ObjectExplorer e vejo que minha base de dados foi criada e a tabela Alunos também. Tudo blz!

Mas quando executo a aplicação no navegador e peço para cadastrar um novo aluno. Esse aluno não aparecia persistido no banco criado.
Fui procurar e encontrei um banco chamado "Persistencia.CadastroAlunosDbContext" que não sei de onde veio. Ele também tem uma tabela Alunos e os dados estão sendo persistidos nele e não no que especifiquei no App.config do projeto Persistencia.
*Obs.: Essa base está sendo criado no que parece ser outra instancia do SQL, mas só tenho uma instalada.*
**Porque o EF está criando esse banco?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como está o app config do projeto principal, que faz o startup ?

Comment: Está default. Não estou alterando nada nele. Nem tem uma connectionStrings

Comment: O problema é que a connectionstring deve ficar no web.config do seu projeto MVC para que sua aplicação saiba qual banco utilizar para persistir, a string de conexão no app.config do seu projeto de persistência só vai servir para gerar as migrações igual você fez. Por padrão, quando o Entity Framework não encontra sua string de conexão (no projeto web) ele vai criar o banco no localDb.

Comment: Pts! Era só isso? Pouxa vida... que decepção... perdi a tarde toda aqui quebrando a cabeça... Deletei o projeto todo 2 vezes. Kkkkkk! Obrigado @GabrielColetta.

Comment: De nada. Testa e compartilhe com a comunidade se isso resolve o problema, se resolver vou fazer uma resposta com a solução para fechar a questão.

Comment: acredito que é só isso mesmo =]

Comment: Realmente @GabrielColetta era isso. Adicionei a connectionStrings no Web.Config e passou a funcionar redondinho. Pode responder e fechar a questão.